# Rtweet package installation issue

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

Recently Twitter changed its characters limits from 140 to 280.
I'm trying to install package rtweet becuase with TwitteR shows only the first 140 characters of the entire tweet.

Running the command:

```
install.packages("rtweet")
```

results in the following console output:

```
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
   binary source needs_compilation
rtweet  0.4.0  0.6.0             FALSE
installing the source package ‘rtweet’
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rtweet_0.6.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2819240 bytes (2.7 MB)
downloaded 2.7 MB
Errore: 18:7: unexpected input
18: Setwd(“
       ^
Esecuzione interrotta
Warning in install.packages :
 running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l 
"C:\Program
 Files\R\R-3.2.2\library" 
C:\Users\SALVAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpA5LW7O/downloaded_packages/rtweet_0.6.0
.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘rtweet’ had non-zero exit status
The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\Salvatore\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpA5LW7O\downloaded_packages’
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like you are running an outdated R version. I'd try updating that first (for example using the `installr` package).

Comment: `rtweet` has `R (≥ 3.1.0)` in `Depends` so that's a perfectly fine R version @tifu. Davide: Clear your workspace. Shutdown R. Restart R. Re-try the package install. This error is on your side and you may even need to startup R in vanilla mode. I say that b/c nothing I know of uses `Setwd` (capital first letter) and you may have that somewhere it's getting sourced during install.